# Does SignalR for ASP.net execute Linq parameters async by default?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub, which returns the result of an Entity Framework call. Back in the old days, you were able to simply write:

```
public IQueryable<MyClass> GetStuff() {
  return MyContext.db.MyTable;
}
```

Nowadays, when we use async programming, I tend to materialize the list inside my method:

```
public async Task<List<MyClass>> GetStuff() {
  return await MyContext.db.MyTable.ToListAsync();
}
```

Now I wonder, if this is really necessary, or if I just could do it the "old" way and SignalR prefers to execute the command asynchronously anyways.

Comment: SignalR doesn't affect how the code inside the actions works. There's no difference between a hub's methods and a controller's actions. In *both* cases, `async/await` is used to release the request thread while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know this, but when I return a Linq query (`IQueryable`) to SignalR, there must be some internal logic to materialize or read the data, right? And the question is, if this SignalR internal materialization is done synchroniously, or if it uses async methods as well. Or in other words: Does the second example bring any benefit, or is it just re-implementing SignalR's default behavior?

Comment: These are completely different libraries. LINQ doesn't even execute the query, the  LINQ provider does - EF, LINQ to Objects, etc.In fact the "old" way suffers from several problems and doesn't do what you think it does. The implicit cast to `IEnumerable<T>` is what executes the query - it's as if you called `.AsEnumerable()`. In fact, `ToList()` just iterates over that enumerable and adds the results to a list

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Or, in other words, my second approach is preferable? And if so, would you suggest to better call `.ToListAsync` or `.AsEnumerable`?